systemd-nspawn and PipeWire
I am running Debian container on systemd-nspawn (host machine is Ubuntu 24.04) and inside container I installed Electron app.
I can run this app with GUI (i. e. when I run it, on my host machine is opened a window, running this app), but app from this container does not have access to speakers, microphone and camera.
So how to configure the container to use host's Pipewire for sound?
My container has only root user. I installed PulseAudion (and also Pipewire) on container, but in /run/user/0 there is no pulse or pipewire directory.
